# insert the content between the matching pattern in shell script

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I want to insert the content between the matching pattern in shell

For example :

file called input.txt :

```
var a = [ ]
```

file called output.txt :

```
1152
1185
1185
```

I want to insert the values from output.txt file to the file input.txt. it should be like

```
var a = [1152 1185 1185]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite simple:

`sed -i "s/\[ \]/[$(cat output.txt | xargs)]/" input.txt`

Comment: you could avoid using `cat` replacing that with this `sed -i "s/\[ \]/[$(< output.txt xargs)]/" input.txt` command

Comment: or even `xargs -a output.txt`

Comment: I need to add comma between those numbers .. is it possible to done through suggested command ("sed "s/[/[ $(xargs < output.txt)/" input.txt") 


Desired output: var a = [123 , 456 , 789]

Comment: add a second command to the `sed` script to change ' ' to ', ' ("space" to "comma followed by space"): `sed  -i "s/\[ \]/[$(xargs -a output.txt)]/; s/ /, /g" input.txt`